# Facebook like button for a win 8 app (WinJS)

Tags: windows-8, facebook-like, winjs

How can I add the like button and comments frame at a Winjs app?

The default code above doesn't work correctly. When I click to like, the API opens another browser:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use this button in Windows 8. You can use SDK but liking a page is not supported.

Here you have sample: [Web authentication broker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)